# How to detect iOS11 programmatically in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios11

I saw in the WWDC video that there's some new swift function to detect iOS 11 availability.

**How do I detect iOS11 with Swift?**

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Swift 3:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
  // Running iOS 11 OR NEWER
} else {
  // Earlier version of iOS
}
```

More information is available in [Declaration Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html) section of Apple's Swift Programming Guide.

Comment: This isn't "some new swift function"; it has been around for a while.

Answer (score 6):

**Objective C:**

```
if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
  // Running iOS 11 OR NEWER
} else {
  // Earlier version of iOS
}
```